# Brew no longer works - macOs 12.6

Tags: macos, homebrew, brew

I work on macOs monterey 12.6 with a M1 pro chip.

I was working on a project with php (8.1), composer and symfony installed and everything was working fine.

I closed my terminal and since when I go back to my folder with my terminal, nothing works anymore.

example : php -v

-bash: php: command not found

composer

env: php: No such file or directory

and since even impossible to reinstall php.

```
brew install php@8.1
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (shivammathur/php and homebrew/cask).
==> New Casks
pictureview

Warning: No available formula with the name "httpd" (dependency of shivammathur/php/php).
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I don't understand, do you know where this could come from and how to solve the problem?

my brew config :

```
brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.6.2
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: b8b195cc64a29595797651720ebb2ea09affb682
Last commit: 4 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: (none)
Core tap last commit: never
Core tap branch: HEAD
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 10
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: 10-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 14.0.0 build 1400
Git: 2.37.0 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.79.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.6-arm64
CLT: 14.0.0.0.1.1661618636
Xcode: N/A
Rosetta 2: false
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open Xcode – it will display an upgrade message
- Confirm and run the upgrades
- Afterwards brew works fine again